# Сразу ли останавливается контейнер после завершения команды stop?

Tags: linux, bash, docker

Написал скрипт, который хочу привязать к крону:

```
docker stop mycontainer
mkdir -p archives
DATE=`date +%d-%m-%y`
FILE=archives/archive_${DATE}.tar.gz
tar -cvzf $FILE database.mv.db
docker start mycontainer
```

Есть сомнение, что архивирование начинается раньше чем докер-контейнер останавливается и соответственно запускается. Не силен в nix'ах, прошу подсказать. Для сведения: файл, который архивируется и получаемый архив, находятся вне контейнера. Спасибо.

Comment: но этот файл находится и используется внутри контейнера?

Comment: Файл базы, которую нужно заархивировать находится вне контейнера. Получаемый архив также должен быть вне контейнера.

Comment: да, файл используется внутри контейнера, там запущено java-приложение на Tomcat, которое подключается к бд

Comment: Вам надо ответить ровно на один вопрос: является ли операция остановки контейнера синхронной или асинхронной. Если второе, нужно искать в документации докера признаки завершения, и отслеживать их.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если все файлы нужно скопировать из контейнера и упаковать на хосте:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

TS="$(date +%d-%m-%y)"
ARCH_PATH="/path/to/archives/dir"
ARCH="archive_${TS}"

mkdir -p "${ARCH_PATH}/${ARCH}"

docker cp mycontainer:/what/to/back/up/path ${ARCH_PATH}/${ARCH} &&
{ docker stop || { echo "Can't stop Docker. Exit"; exit 1; }

cd "${ARCH_PATH}"
tar -cvzf  ${ARCH}.tar.gz ${ARCH}

docker start mycontainer

rm -r "${ARCH_PATH}/${ARCH}"; }
# end of script
```

`&&` - выполнить после успешного завершения 0

`||` - не успешное 1

Comment: Посмотрите, что конкретно у вас выполняется в случае успешного завершения, а что нет, а также что не зависит от кода возврата. Ну и к вопросу автора ваши правки имеют косвенное отношение.

Comment: @0andriy поправил. стилистику сменил - как бы я писал для себя с оглядкой на поддержку и использования другими.

Comment: Всем спасибо! То, что надо!

Comment: 1. Мне кажется должно быть `usr` вместо `use`, хотя с  shell так (запуск через env) обычно никто не делает. 2. Вы вначале копируете, потом останавливаете docker. Это 100% гарантия проблем, если программа держит файл открытым. 3. Вместо `cp` лучше использовать rsync. 4. `cd` излишен, `tar` умеет ходить по каталогам сам. 5. Ну и вообще лучше смотреть в сторону CRIU (Checkpointing-Restore In User space).